# TypeError: can't convert Pathname to String

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm getting `TypeError: can't convert Pathname to String` after requiring r18n file in the app.

myapp.rb

```
require 'sinatra/r18n'
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sinatra-r18n'
```

Any idea?

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? What else is in `myapp.rb`? Are you calling `require 'bundler/setup'`? What else is in the `Gemfile`? Bundler won't run without a `source` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update sinatra-r18n, it is old issue.